# Perform an action when you press the physical menu button

Tags: android, key-events

I would like to do some action when you press the menu button, but it does not work.
If we use KEYCODE_BACK instead of KEYCODE_MENU, it works.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {

        Log.d("KeyEvent", "MENU Pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: See in your logcat if you are really using KEYCODE_MENU and not KEYCODE_HOME or something else, check this [list][1] 


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: "just put log.d("KeyEvent","Inside method.. --> " + keycode ) in fist line of this method.. check log after then.."  --> Writes only if I press back.

Answer (score 0):

try in keyup instead of keyDown .. like this..

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
      Log.d("KeyEvent", "MENU Pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: just put log.d("KeyEvent","Inside method.. --> " + keycode  ) in fist line of this method.. check log after then..

Comment: Now, I am curious, this onkeydown/onkeyup methods that you are overriding is of your Activity or is it your view... what I meant is, Is this method inside a class which extends View???

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case this method is inside a BaseActivity which my main activity extends from

Comment: @CRUSADER, what is the difference in behavior when it is implemented on Activity vs View? I have one case where it is defined on Activity and it worked until the platform was switched from v21 to v22.